# Playstore: Update rollout percentage via Publishing API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am using this [Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#publishing) for Playstore and following this Google's [Python examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/python) to access the Playstore console.

Is it possible to update **only the rollout percentage** of an existing version currently being rolled out ?

I tried using this `service.edits().tracks().update().execute()` function with `track = 'production'` but it creates a new "release" with existing APKs.

Comment: Did you look at the "userFraction" field here? https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks#resource

Comment: @Pierre I did. For example, my rollout was at 50%. Then I used this command with `userFraction` = 0.6 which created a new release with 60% rollout.